# Crossfilter Remove Records

Tags: crossfilter

I am trying to remove data from crossfilter. The [docs](https://github.com/square/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#wiki-crossfilter_remove) state:

> crossfilter.**remove()**
>
> Removes all records that match the current filters from this crossfilter.

```
var db = crossfilter([1, 2, 3]),
dimension = db.dimension(Number);
dimension.filter(1);
db.remove();
```

I would expect this to return [2, 3], but I am getting [ ].

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8uAB9/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed 1 but still had it filtered with

```
dimension.filter(1);
```

reset with this:

```
dimension.filterAll();
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8uAB9/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Best I understand it, `crossfilteredObject.remove();` removes ALL objects from the original crossfilteredObject.

There are no objects in your db object for the dimension to draw upon.